# Mailgun Unsubscribe URL for Campaign

Tags: mailgun, unsubscribe

Through the [Mailgun Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-unsubscribes), there are 3 unsubscribe links:

> `%unsubscribe_url%` link to unsubscribe recipient from all messages sent by given domain 
>   `%tag_unsubscribe_url%` link to unsubscribe from all tags provided in the message
>   `%mailing_list_unsubscribe_url%` link to unsubscribe from future messages sent to a mailing list

The documentation references being able to unsubscribe from campaigns: [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/best_practices.html#unsubscribe-handling).

How do I add a campaign_unsubscribe_url or something similar?

Currently, I am working around by tagging.

Comment: You may add a tag for your campaign so that %tag_unsubscribe_url% can be used?

Comment: @Muatik, I'm already doing that.